# SAPI STT in javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, speech-recognition, sapi

I'm new to javascript and was wondering if there are any tutorials on how to implement speech to text and speech recognition through SAPI. The only examples I've found so far are TTS and how to spit back text. And the questions already posted aren't really giving me any info I can take from.

I know that you have to create an ActiveXObject, but I can't really understand the Microsoft SAPI website since none of the examples are in javascript and I don't know any of the syntax. I plan on making an HTML app that can use speech recognition to preform tasks in a program.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAPI objects aren't marked Safe For Scripting (because they're not) and can't easily be used from JavaScript.   I've done it, but you have to turn off *tons* of internet security options in order to do so.  I wouldn't pursue that path, particularly for a public-facing website.

Comment: I'm just kind of locked up right now because this speech recognition has to work in IE. Do you know of any other ways to do STT that will work with JavaScript and IE?

Comment: @Rigial9 Does it have to be a website?  If you can make it a standalone app (say, a WinPhone universal app), there are a lot more options.  SR on websites is still really experimental.

Comment: The prototype we're doing right now is basically just one giant script that uses node.js and socket.io for back and forths. I'm sure in the future it will probably become a standalone app, but for now it's just a website. If it wasn't developed in IE I would have some options but I guess I'm stuck now. Thanks for all the help.